# Can I list file names (or their parent directories) that were recently deleted using rm in OS X?

Tags: macos, shell, data-recovery, logging, rm

Is it possible to find out which files and directories have recently been deleted by `rm` in OS X? Or failing that, is it possible to find which parent directories have had files or directories within it deleted?

The OS version is Snow Leopard.

**Background:** Last night, rvm (ruby version manager) did `rm -rf` of the ~/ruby directory from the home directory. (This bug has [since been fixed](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/commit/1e430094f919c1f7297d5598be2639a7e6e265bc))

Ideally, I'd like to know what files within the ~/ruby directory were deleted, but failing that, I'd like to know if rvm deleted anything outside of ~/ruby .

**In case anyone's wondering about backups...**: Just about everything within ~/ruby is a git project that has a remote repo, and I have a fairly recent Time Machine backup (only 20 days old).

Comment: Are you looking specifically for this case or is this something you would generally like to know? In this case, you should be able to get your information by comparing with your git repo or your backup, right? Having said that, I doubt you can get any information about rm history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using unix `find` to look for directories that had a recent modification date. It indicated that the only folders that had a recent modification date (apart from some boring cached data directories) was ~/ruby and a subfolder that contained undeleteable files.